# Custom error handling in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have build language specific custom error pages.
and i am using http errors in web.config.still i am getting default iis error response.
here are the code sniplets

```
<httpErrors defaultResponseMode="File" errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="error" path="error.htm"/>
</httpErrors>
```

i have overidden mode to allow in httperror section in apphostconfig.
i have also set custom error mode to off.
and i am not using standard ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/ServerError">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/ServerError" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: hi i have created language specific error pages using http errors in IIS.

But have few issues. 
i have set language preference in IE. 


So whenever i run my application error pages are getting displayed only in IE prefered language.
so if i change application language. its not selecting application language only error pages are getting displayed in IE prefered language..


Please put some light on this.